# Addtion to exciting function SumCellsByColor

Tags: excel, vba, function

Thanks for a great forum. I have a question concerning an existing code (not my own). The code itself works perfectly for the purpose, but now I need some additional and I can’t figure out how to get it to work. The original code can be seen below.

I need the function to be able to have another criteria. I need the code to be able to only sum if colmn D is true given an input. Something like IF cells(x;x) = “MJE” then… 
I hope it make sense otherwise please fell free to ask questions.

```
Function SumCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range)
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim sumRes

    Application.Volatile
    sumRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
            sumRes = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cellCurrent, sumRes)
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    SumCellsByColor = sumRes
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of doing this but the easiest I can think of would be:

```
Function SumCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range, column_offset As Long, TextToMatch As String)
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim sumRes

    Application.Volatile
    sumRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color And cellCurrent.Offset(0, column_offset).Value = TextToMatch Then
            sumRes = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cellCurrent, sumRes)
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    SumCellsByColor = sumRes
End Function
```

You would then call it in your example with:

```
=SumCellsByColor(G$2:G$95;$C111,-3,"MJE")
```

Where column D is 3 to the left of column G, ie. offset -3.